# how to replace line numbers in vim

Tags: regex, vim

Here is my sample file in vi

```
1./*
2. * C  Program to Build Binary Tree if Inorder or Postorder Traversal as Input
3. *
4. *                     40
5. *                    /  \
6. *                   20   60
7. *                  /  \   \
8. *                 10  30   80
9. *                           \
10. *                           90    
11. *             (Given Binary Search Tree)    
12. */
13.#include <stdio.h>
14.#include <stdlib.h>
15. 
16.struct btnode
17.{
18.    int value;
19.    struct btnode *l;
20.    struct btnode *r;
21.}*root = NULL, *temp = NULL;
22. 
23.typedef struct btnode N;
24.void insert();
25.N* bt(int arr[],int,int);
26.N* new(int);
27.void inorder(N *t);
28.void create();
29.void search(N *t);
30.void preorder(N *t);
31.void postorder(N *t);
32. 
33.void main()
34.{
35.    int ch, i, n;
36.    int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 90};
37.    n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
38. 
39.    printf("\n1- Inorder\n");
40.    printf("2 - postorder\n");
41.    printf("\nEnter choice : ");
42.    scanf("%d", &ch);
43.    switch (ch)
44.    {
45.    case 1:
46.        root = bt(arr, 0, n-1); 
47.        printf("Given inorder traversal as input\n");
48.        for (i = 0;i< = 6;i++)
49.            printf("%d->", arr[i]);
50.        printf("\npreorder traversal of tree\n");
51.        preorder(root);
52.        printf("\ninorder traversal of tree\n");
53.        inorder(root);
54.        printf("\npostorder traversal of tree\n");
55.        postorder(root);
56.        break;
57.    case 2:
58.        insert();
59.        printf("\npreorder traversal of tree\n");
60.        preorder(root);
61.        printf("\nInorder traversal of tree\n");
62.        inorder(root);
63.        printf("\npostorder traversal of tree\n");
64.        postorder(root);
65.        break;
66.        default:printf("enter correct choice");
67.    }
68.}
69. 
70./* To create a new node */
71.N* new(int val)
72.{
73.    N* node = (N*)malloc(sizeof(N));
74. 
75.    node->value = val;
76.    node->l = NULL;
77.    node->r  =  NULL;
78.    return node;
79.}
80. 
81./* To create a balanced binary search tree */
82.N* bt(int arr[], int first, int last)
83.{
84.    int mid;
85. 
86.    N* root = (N*)malloc(sizeof(N));
87.    if (first > last)
88.        return NULL;
89.    mid = (first + last) / 2;
90.    root = new(arr[mid]);
91.    root->l = bt(arr, first, mid - 1);
92.    root->r = bt(arr, mid + 1, last);
93.    return root;
94.}
95. 
96./* Insert a node in the tree */
97.void insert()
98.{
99.    int arr1[] = {10, 30, 20, 90, 80, 60, 40}, i;
100. 
101.    printf("Given post order traversal array\n");
102.    for (i = 0;i <= 6;i++)
103.    {
104.        printf("%d->", arr1[i]);
105.     }
106.    for (i = 6;i >= 0;i--) 
107.    {
108.        create(arr1[i]);
109.        if (root =  = NULL)
110.            root = temp;
111.        else
112.            search(root);
113.    }
114.}
115. 
116./*Create a node */
117.void create(int data)
118.{
119.    temp = (N *)malloc(1*sizeof(N));
120. 
121.    temp->value = data;
122.    temp->l = temp->r = NULL;
123.}
124. 
125./* Search for the appropriate position to insert the new node */
126.void search(N *t)
127.{
128.    if ((temp->value>t->value)&&(t->r != NULL))
129.        search(t->r);
130.    else if ((temp->value>t->value)&&(t->r  == NULL))
131.        t->r = temp;
132.    else if ((temp->value<t->value)&&(t->l != NULL))
133.        search(t->l);
134.    else if ((temp->value<t->value)&&(t->l == NULL))
135.        t->l = temp;
136.}
137. 
138./* to display inorder of tree */
139.void inorder(N *t)
140.{
141.    if (t->l != NULL)
142.        inorder(t->l);
143.    printf("%d->", t->value);
144.    if (t->r != NULL)
145.        inorder(t->r);
146.}
147. 
148./* to display preorder traversal of tree */
149.void preorder(N *t) 
150.{
151.    printf("%d->", t->value);
152.    if (t->l != NULL)
153.        inorder(t->l);
154.    if (t->r != NULL)
155.        inorder(t->r);
156.}
157. 
158./* to display postorder traversal of tree */
159.void postorder(N *t) 
160.{
161.    if (t->l != NULL)
162.        inorder(t->l);
163.    if (t->r != NULL)
164.        inorder(t->r);
165.    printf("%d->", t->value);
166.}
```

In above code what will be a correct regex expression to replace numbers with a blank in vi.
I want to replace the line numbers with space in vi.
I searched on internet I got various tutorials to put line numbers in file but how to replace line numbers if they are already there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following substitution:

```
:%s/^\d\+\./ /
```

where

- **`^`** match the beginning of the line
- **`\d\+`** match one or more digits
- **`\.`** match a dot
- **`/ /`** replace with a space

Comment: This doesn't need \v ?

Comment: @zzxyz you could use `\v` but the regex would have to be `\v^\d+.`

Comment: @Sergio: I guess you mean `\v^\d+\.`

Comment: @yolenoyer Yes I meant `\.` to match a literal dot.

Answer (score 2):

A simple command could solve your problem:

```
:%norm df.

: .................. command mode
% .................. whole file
norm ............... normal mode
df. ................ delete until the first dot
```

Comment: A shade easier: `:%norm cf. ` (with a space there at the end). No need to go into visual mode; the text doesn't need to be highlighted etc. And if you don't want the space, then just `:norm df.`, this time without the trailing space.

Comment: I did not know about 'f'. Best thing since 'ci'

Comment: @zzxyz - `vimtutor` for great justice. Also- note the difference between 'f' and 't' in that position... (See `:help f` and read four or so paragraphs.)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang - I keep doing vimtutor--which is very short--and finding new things despite being pretty sure I've absorbed the whole thing each time I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the lines do have a number at the start, this deletes it plus the dot:

```
:%s/\d*.
```

If you do want it replaced with a space, use:

```
:%s/\d*./ /
```